# wp7 mediaelement vs mediaplayer launcher

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can we get events like start, stop, pause of a video using mediaplayerlauncher and also can we get the length of the video played using the same or we need to go with mediaelement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launchers don't allow to communicate with the OS app in any way if no property is defined.
If you want/need control, you need the mediaelement.